# Why does the following code output 2 instead of 1?

Tags: php

I recently stumbled upon this question at an interview. And I did not knew the correct answer. I can't understand why PHP outputs 2 instead of 1.

```
class a
{
    public static $myvar;
    function __construct($x = 1)
    {
        self::$myvar = $x;
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    public static $myvar;

    function __construct($x = 2)
    {
        self::$myvar = $x;
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$obj = new b();
echo $obj::$myvar;
```

Comment: `public static $myvar` is declared in each class. That's why `A::myvar` is not the same as `B::myvar`.

Comment: I don't get it. If I var_dump $x in the 'a' constructor it outputs 2...

Comment: No, it does not; https://3v4l.org/1jDC4

Comment: I got most of your answer though. You are referring to late static binding.

Comment: __Why__ do you declare `public static $myvar` in both classes? Declare in parent class only and it will be available in child class too.

Comment: It was a test. this is not production code.

Comment: well my guess is that if the inherited class has a static variable with the same name as the parent class, then when accessing it, it will go to the lowest available option in the inheritance tree. good to know